# Searching for a part like 48989 but without the pins

Tags: technic, piece-information, shopping, clone-brands, connections

I am searching for a part like LEGO [48989](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48989#T=C), but without the 4 pins.

[image]

The manufacturer doesn't matter as long as the part is compatible with LEGO bricks.
Also, a combination of parts is ok if it has the same function and no overlapping parts.

The construction problem:

- the upper holes will hold pins with friction ridges (3L or normal)
- the sideways hole will hold a pin with friction ridges (3L or normal)

Comment: Do they have to be pins with friction ridges ? Can they be pins with axles and friction ridges like [Technic, Axle 1L with Pin with Friction Ridges](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43093) or [Technic, Axle 1L with Pin 2L with Friction Ridges](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11214) or [Technic, Axle 2L with Pin with Friction Ridges](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18651).

Comment: Yes, unfortunatly it has to be a friction pin. If there would exist a 3l pin with axle-friction-axle, i could use your first recommendation.

Comment: Lego has recently released a part to get closer to the ideal, by removing two of the four pins. https://brickset.com/parts/design-2393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the part on several marketplaces on aliexpress and bought it. I don't know if its from Cada or other clone company, but the parts are working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Your updated question mentions axle holes are not an option for your needs, and just pin holes are allowed. There's no LEGO part (I know of) with that exact topology, nor do I see a way of combining parts to achieve the desired topology within a 3L size restriction.

If none of the below suggestions suit your exact needs, and assuming cutting off the pins of a [48989](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48989) part is not an option, then non-LEGO parts are your only option it seems. I'll have to defer to someone else in that case. I'll leave this answer up, since it might provide inspiration.

### LEGO Technic connectors with 90 degree offset holes, limited to 3L size (but with axle holes)

The closest is probably [Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Perpendicular 3L with Center Pin Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32184), albeit with axle holes rather than pin holes :

[image]

There exist similar parts as well, like eg. [Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Perpendicular 3L with 2 Pin Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42003) :

[image]

Or the smaller [Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Perpendicular](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6536) :

[image]

### LEGO Technic connectors with 90 degree offset holes, with just pin holes (but exceeding 3L size)

There are some parts that have just pin holes, offset by 90 degrees, like [Technic, Pin Connector Perpendicular 2 x 2 Bent](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44809) :

[image]

Or the bigger and more recent [Technic, Pin Connector Block, Liftarm 1 x 3 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=39793) :

[image]

Or even [Technic, Liftarm, Modified H-Shape Thick 3 x 5 Perpendicular](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14720) :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Those parts don't fit for my construction problem.

Comment: @spoekes : could you then clarify your construction problem ? What are you trying to achieve ? You can edit your question with additional details.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @spoekes : Updated my answer accordingly - unfortunately no exact match for your desired topology.